# Calculated measure not working with DAX filter

Tags: powerbi

I have created **NBRevenue** Measure to get **SUM of Revenue** with two conditions as filter as per below screen shot, The issue is when i add **[CurrentYear]** then the data displayed in below screenshot(1) is wrong but when I hard code 2020 in screenshot(2) then data is correct.

I did check that the **[CurrentYear]** is whole number and the table **'AST DMNewLostMeasures'[Year]** is too whole number.

**Wrong Result- ScreenShot(1)**
[image]

**Correct Result - Screenshot(2)**
[image]

I need to make this dynamic and hence please let me know what wrong I am doing or any other approach/suggestion would be great.

**CurrentYear Formula**

[image]

Comment: Can you also show your code for [CurrectYear]? Is that a Measure or Custom Column?

Comment: Hey @mkRabbani, I have added CurrentYear measure formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a **Year** slicer rather than using a Measure reference inside your formula. That will make everything dynamic and result will be populated as per selected Year in the slicer. Your Revenue code should be as below-

```
NBRevenue = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('AST DMNewLostMeasures'[Revenue]),
    FILTER(
        'AST DMNewLostMeasures',
        'AST DMNewLostMeasures'[MeasureType] = "NewRevenue/Policies"
    )
)
```

You can also change your **CurrentYear** measure as below-

```
CurrentYear = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX('AST DMNewLostMeasures'[Year]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('AST DMNewLostMeasures'),
        'AST DMNewLostMeasures'[MeasureType] = "NewRevenue/Policies"
    )
)
```

Comment: Hey @mkRabbani, I do not have an option of adding slicer here due to business.

Comment: Hi @Babulal, please check the updated code for CurrentYear I have added to the answer.

Comment: Great @mkRabbani, Changing CurrentYear measure formula by adding ALL did work, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi @Babulal nice to see it helped and worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `CurrentYear` measure returns what you expect, I'd recommend setting it as a variable rather than recalculating it for every row in your filter table:

```
NBRevenue =
VAR CurrYear = [CurrentYear]
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    SUM('AST DMNewLostMeasures'[Revenue]),
    FILTER(
        'AST DMNewLostMeasures',
        'AST DMNewLostMeasures'[MeasureType] = "NewRevenue/Policies"
            && 'AST DMNewLostMeasures'[Year] = CurrYear
    )
)
```